# C# library to syntax-highlight Python code on a HTML page?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, syntax-highlighting, ironpython

Question:

Is there any C#/VB.NET library that can produce HTML output from Python sourcecode ?
I mean display the Python sourcecode syntax-highlighted on a website ?

It should be C#/.NET code, not a JavaScript library. 
This is because I highlight many programming languages, and their HTML is already generated server-side, so I really can't use a JavaScript library.

Comment: I know you said you can't use a JS library, but such intensive UI tasks are things you better do at the client to save your server resources. You can also choose to just enable the javascript for specific regions on the page, so it doesn't interfere.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Actipro CodeHighlighter](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/products/dotnet/aspnet/codehighlighter/)?